# How to always run/refresh datatables?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, datatables, react-data-table-component

When I do some action in my react application like, update or delete, the data tables cannot run, the data tables only run when refreshing the page  How can I get it to refresh automatically?

```
//Datatable Modules
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables"
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
import $ from 'jquery'; 

import { useEffect } from "react";

//initialize datatable
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable();
   } ,100);
});

useEffect(() => {
    init();
  },[])

  const init = () => {
    employeeService.getAll()
    .then(response => {
      setEmployees(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Something wrong', error);
    })
  }
```

the return container

```
    <table id="example" className="table table-bordered table-striped">
      ...
    </table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question, or point you in a useful direction? [Not able to display data streaming from websocket to dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67149810/12567365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you're looking for needs the usage of live data updates,
You can use the native [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) API, or use a simpler api like [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) to make a connection between the Client and the Server (Emit | Receive) and update the table data...
Good luck learning WebSockets!